# Delphi How to get default value for property using RTTI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, rtti

If I have a class like this:

```
TServerSettings = class(TSettings)
strict private
    FHTTPPort : Integer;
published
    property HTTPPort : Integer read FHTTPPort write FHTTPPort default 80;
end;
```

How can I get the `default` attribute of the `HTTPPort` property using RTTI?

Comment: With old or new RTTI ?

Comment: Whatever is used in Delphi XE3. Copyright says 1995-2012.

Comment: There are both... Just remember my comment and do not blame me when you'll be doing something *deeper* and the old RTTI won't suffice :-)

Comment: The `default` you're using doesn't mean what you think it does. It's a *storage specifier*. It only decides whether or not the property is streamed to the DFM at designtime. (In this case, if  the `HTTPPort` property is `80` when the .DFM is streamed, the `HTTPPort` property is not saved.) See the [Storage Specifiers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Properties#Storage_Specifiers) section: *Note: Property values are not automatically initialized to the default value. That is, the default directive controls only when property values are saved to the form file...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.TypInfo;

type
  TMyClass = class
  strict private
    FMyValue: Integer;
  published
    property MyValue: Integer read FMyValue default 42;
  end;

var
  obj: TMyClass;
  PropInfo: PPropInfo;

begin
  obj := TMyClass.Create;
  PropInfo := GetPropInfo(obj, 'MyValue');
  Writeln(PropInfo.Default);
end.
```

Note that the class as it stands, just as is so for that in your question, is broken. The system will not automatically initialise properties to their default value when an instance is created. You would need to add a constructor to this class to do that.

Comment: Thanks that works but what if `MyValue` is not an integer but a bool or so? Then I get something like incompatible type boolean and integer.

Comment: You'll have to cast it. Default property values are only available for ordinal properties. So, for a boolean, 0 means false, 1 means true.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Default`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Rtti.TRttiInstanceProperty.Default) property of the `TRttiInstanceProperty` class

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Rtti,
  System.SysUtils;


type
  TServerSettings = class
  strict private
      FHTTPPort : Integer;
  published
      property HTTPPort : Integer read FHTTPPort write FHTTPPort default 80;
  end;

var
   L : TRttiType;
   P : TRttiProperty;
begin
  try
     P:= TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TServerSettings.ClassInfo).GetProperty('HTTPPort');
     if P is TRttiInstanceProperty  then
       Writeln(TRttiInstanceProperty(P).Default);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```